# HTTPS POST requests from browsers, why do I have to use an add-on?

Tags: http, browser, request, add-on

I have HTTP Requester add-on for firefox to make HTTPS POST requests. I just don't get why can't I simply copy and paste my HTTPS request URL directly in my browser ? Isn't it the same ? Why do I have to use an add on ?

Comment: I would appreciate if you told me why my question is downvoted.

Comment: When using the addressbar in the browser you are making get requests and not post requests. Neither do you have the ability to add a content body.

Comment: To send a post request you can use a HTML `form` using method `POST`. No plugin required.

Comment: before installing the addon you should have read about Get and Post requests

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful answers. 
@Professor: I know about them ,but I got mixed up since the API i'm using responded to my request URL from my browser exactly like it responded from the HTTP Requester using POST. This could be silly, but I thought it chooses the correct method automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because if you just paste your request directly on your browser, you are going to issue a `GET` HTTP command and not a `POST` one.

`POST` are a little bit more complicated to format. You could use a TELNET command to issue a post command like this:

```
$ telnet YOUR_IP 80
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.111.111.26

key1=value1&key2=value2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a HTML form to issue a POST request from your browser:

```
<form action="URL_you_want_to_post_to" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Send"></input>
</form>
```

You might also want to look at command line tools like [HTTPIE](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie) or [CURL](http://curl.haxx.se/).